# Datasource Paging Issue (Revised)

Tags: google-app-maker

A simple testing setup: department: employee, 1:M and a search form that allows filtering on Emploee FirstName =, lastname =, email contains, age >=, join date <= and related department =.

A search form with widgets bound to parameters of a cloud SQL datasource query script.

A Submit button on the search form which opens up a query results page with a table bound to the cloud SQL query script datasource.

query script

var params = query.parameters;

```
return getEmployeeRecords_( 
  params.param_FirstName, 
  params.param_LastName, 
  params.param_Email, 
  params.param_StartDate, 
  params.param_Age, 
  params.param_Department
);
```

and

```
function getEmployeeRecords_( firstName, lastName, email, startDate, age,     
department) {

 var ds = app.models.Employee.newQuery();

 if ( firstName !== null ) {
    ds.filters.FirstName._equals = firstName;
 }
 if ( lastName !== null ) {
    ds.filters.LastName._equals = lastName;
 }
 if ( email !== null) {
    ds.filters.Email._contains = email;
 }
 if ( startDate !== null) {
    ds.filters.StartDate._greaterThanOrEquals = startDate;
 }
 if ( age !== null) {
    ds.filters.Age._lessThanOrEquals = parseInt(age, 10);
 }
 if ( department !== null) {
    ds.filters.Department.Department._equals = department;
 }

 var records = ds.run();

 // intention is to store this value for future use
 var recs = records.length;

 return records;
}
```

On the results page for the query script datasource paging is just broken. A query that correctly returns 8 records where the query page size is set to 5 allows me to get the pager to go to page 1000 if I wished, but the datasource always stays on the first page of records. With page size set to e.g., 100 the correct result set is clearly displayed.

In fact everything I do with this sort of query has paging issues. If I insert this code

```
var ds = app.models.Employee.newQuery();
//ds.filters.FirstName._equals = firstName;
//ds.filters.LastName._equals = lastName;
//ds.filters.Email._contains = '.com';
//ds.filters.StartDate._greaterThanOrEquals = startDate;
ds.filters.Age._lessThanOrEquals = 40;
//ds.filters.Department.Department._equals = department;
ds.sorting.Age._ascending();
var records = ds.run();
return records;
```

directly into the datasource query script I still have similar paging issues.

If I use a query builder script such as

```
(
FirstName =? :param_FirstName and
LastName =? :param_LastName and
Email contains? :param_Email and
StartDate >=? :param_Startdate and
Age <=? :param_Age and
Department.Department =? :param_Department
)
```

and bindings such as

@datasources.Search_Query_Builder.query.parameters.param_FirstName

this works without issue. The same with direct filtering, where we use bindings such as

@datasources.Employee.query.filters.FirstName._equals

Anyone any ideas in terms of what is wrong with this stuff. We need query scripts for more controle, e.g., the ability to retrieve a count of records and where you have to filter for a condition where you restrict data, e.g. a logged in user is related to a client which in turn is related to a property and the property value is restricted according to client.

... Just looking at a real application under development and the use of a query script within the datasource query script editor, no parameters, no binding, just this code:-

```
var ds = app.models.Incident.newQuery();
ds.filters.Id._greaterThanOrEquals = 200;
ds.filters.Id._lessThanOrEquals = 300;
var records = ds.run();
return records;
```

and a page size set to 20 and again the paging is up the creek, never moves beyond the first page of records despite the page number incrementing.

Comment: Markus, I've re-submitted the original question you responded to stackoverflow.com/questions/56139909/datasource-paging-issue because I covered several issues and I could have been clearer in my question. Cloud SQL query scripting and paging is the problem. If you (or anyone) can let me have any ideas as to the cause and solution to this paging issue it would be appreciated. Otherwise I can't see me having any further use for App Maker as it is

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions how to address this issue, although it is still unclear what exactly is causing the paging issue and whether or not my suggestions will fix the underlying issue. However, in my own application environment I have several instances where I use a standard SQL model and I apply filters to a datasource from that model and then have a concurrent calculated model (datasource) that returns the total count of records that meet the filters applied to my other datasource. Here we go:

Create a new datasource under your Employee model, leave it on the default 'Query Builder' type, adjust the query page size to your preference, but preferably to something that you know will return more than one page of records when querying the datasource. Uncheck the 'automatically load data' property unless you want to load all records when first going to your page where you set your filters. Do not enter anything in the query builder.

For the calculated datasource that you called Employee_RecordCount add your parameters, FirstName_equals, LastName_equals, Email_contains, StartDate_greaterequals, Age_lessequals, and Departments_equals, if you have not already. In this calculated model you should have a field called RecordCount. In the query script section of this datasource you should put your function as `return getEmployeeRecords_(query)`.

In your server script section where your getEmployeeRecords function is the code should be as follows:

```
function getEmployeeRecords_(query) {
 var params = query.parameters;
 var ds = app.models.Employee.newQuery();

 if (params.FirstName_equals !== null ) {
    ds.filters.FirstName._equals = params.FirstName_equals;
 }
 if (params.LastName_equals !== null ) {
    ds.filters.LastName._equals = params.LastName_equals;
 }
 if (params.Email_contains !== null) {
    ds.filters.Email._contains = params.Email_contains;
 }
 if (params.StartDate_greaterequals !== null) {
    ds.filters.StartDate._greaterThanOrEquals = params.StartDate_greaterequals;
 }
 if (params.Age_lessequals !== null) {
    ds.filters.Age._lessThanOrEquals = parseInt(params.Age_lessequals, 10);
 }
 if (params.Department_equals !== null) {
    ds.filters.Department.Department._equals = params.Department_equals;
 }
 var records = ds.run();

 // update calculated model with record count
 var calculatedModelRecord = app.models.Employee_RecordCount.newRecord();
 calculatedModelRecord.RecordCount = records.length;

 return [calculatedModelRecord];
}
```

Now go to your search page, create a new panel or form set it to the same new datasource that you created. Make sure you have all your appropriate fields and change the binding of these fields to:

```
@datasource.query.filters.firstName._equals
@datasource.query.filters.lastName._equals
@datasource.query.filters.email._contains
@datasource.query.filters.StartDate._greaterThanOrEquals
@datasource.query.filters.Age._lessThanOrEquals
@datasource.query.fitlers.Department.Department._equals
```

The button that initiates your search should have the following code:

```
var ds = widget.datasource;
ds.load(function() {
  app.showPage(app.pages.YourSearchResultPage);
}
var calculatedDs = app.datasources.Employee_RecordCount;
var props = calculatedDs.properties;
props.FirstName_equals = ds.query.filters.firstName._equals;
props.LastName_equals = ds.query.filters.lastName._equals;
props.Email_contains = ds.query.filters.email._contains;
props.StartDate_greaterequals = ds.query.filters.StartDate._greaterThanOrEquals;
props.Age_lessequals = ds.query.filters.Age._lessThanOrEquals;
props.Department_equals = ds.query.filters.Department.Department._equals;
calculatedDs.load();
```

Now go to your search result page and make sure the you have the following elements:

1. A panel that the datasource is set to Employee_RecordCount. Inside
   this panel create a label and set the binding to
   `@datasource.item.RecordCount`.
2. A table that has the datasource set
   to the same datasource as created in the first step. Make sure your
   table has 'pagination' turned on.

That should be all, and this works in my application. It is a pain to set up, but I'm afraid it is the only workaround to have a total count of records. I should note that I have never had any paging issues either.

Comment: Markus, many thanks for your input. Your code worked very well. Paging worked from the off. I had an issue with the record count returning the total for all records, but having re-loaded the project it now works fine.

Comment: I'm still somewhat miffed by not beinag able to use paging iwith a simple cloud SQL datasource. Would you mind as a matter of interest taking a datasource and running a cloud sql query against it, say the bare minimum:-

    var ds = app.models.Employee.newQuery();
    ds.filters.Email._contains = '.info';
    var records = ds.run();
    return records;

and see if your paging works. I have the above with page size of 5, returns 11 records but can't move beyond the first page of results.

Comment: I'm just setting a page datasource to the query, dropping a table into it with no sorting or deleting and setting sorting in the datasource itself.

Comment: Won’t be able to today. Not till Monday again. What is it that’s not working? Are you referring to your old setup or is there something with my suggested setup? I think from here it might be better to maybe see some screenshots from your page setup and widget bindings. Do note that calculated or SQL calculated datasources have always exhibited a bug regarding paging. But I think you said this is a default sql datasource?

Comment: Next week Markus fine. Paging is fine, record count ... I probably need to remove the calc RecordCount record between queries.

But what I was asking re. running a simple cloud sql is can you reproduce the paging behaviour? No recordcount code, no calc models, just a straight cloud SQL model and datasource script that filters a few records more than a page full and a table set to this datasource with paging... what do you see?

Comment: Markus, apologies, my mistake. I had a couple of mis-matching parameter names and that was causing the problem. I've tested your code extensively with single and multiple ANDs and it work 100%.

If you could spare the time to give me your feedback on the paging problem using the most minimal of cloud SQL queries as above I would be grateful. A query such as

var ds = app.models.Employee.newQuery();
var records = ds.run();
return records;

with no filters causes paging problems

Comment: @SilverFox I looked into this again and I do not have any paging issues even with an empty query. In fact most of my datasources get auto loaded without any query filters and it returns a full count on record counts and my pagers are working just fine. Might need to explain some more what is going on.

Comment: Markus, thanks for yout time. The issue is quite simple. I create a cloud SQL datasource under an existing datasource, I use the query

var ds = app.models.Incident.newQuery();
ds.filters.Status.Status._equals = 'Open';
var records = ds.run();
return records;

I set page size of 15. Query returns 37 records. Returned records match query but using pager it just refreshes the first page and incremnts the page counter. I can 'navigate' to page 15 but still first page. So my question was ... can you reproduce this behaviour, because to me it just seems aberrant, not what should be expected.